# Tem como colocar uma imagem em cima de um botão ou na background?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="bcen" onclick="if(--this.textContent<=0) alert('You\'ve won!');"  value="10">10</button>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("bcen").style.width =
"300px"; //Size
    document.getElementById("bcen").style.height =
"300px"; //Size

document.getElementById('bcen').style.fontSize="200px";   //size   

document.getElementById('bcen').style.color = 'red' 

document.getElementById('bcen').style.backgroundColor='blue';

document.getElementById('bcen').style.borderRadius = "50%";

document.getElementById('bcen').style.outline = "none";
      </script/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Tipo assim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)?

Comment: Não funcionou aqui amigo!

Comment: Poderia atualizar a pergunta com a sua tentativa?

Comment: Sim arrumei da uma olhada ai!

Comment: Tem como me ajudar?

Comment: ? Atualizei ai ja mano

Answer (score 1):

Basta setar a propriedade [`backgroundImage`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp), não esqueça que seu valor deve ser sempre `'url(exemplo.png)'`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="bcen" onclick="if(--this.textContent<=0) alert('You\'ve won!');" value="10">10</button>
  <script>
    //Fundo no corpo da página
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTNylMnVaVWb0dAzVvBOxf8BiyTGlS8WK_3UZ1l2G0Ut0WfFb_Y)';

    document.getElementById("bcen").style.width = "300px"; //Size
    document.getElementById("bcen").style.height = "300px"; //Size
    document.getElementById('bcen').style.fontSize = "200px"; //size   
    document.getElementById('bcen').style.color = 'red'
    document.getElementById('bcen').style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxcBMtRs4ePVWb1m3pTBeALxaO_jIDZMMeTccOW-F7rCN4krU)';    document.getElementById('bcen').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    document.getElementById('bcen').style.borderRadius = "50%";
    document.getElementById('bcen').style.outline = "none";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Uma observação, como você está fazendo várias alterações no mesmo elemento é aconselhável a guardar a referência para esse elemento numa variável, veja como o código fica menor, mais limpo e mais simples de entender:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <button id="bcen" onclick="if(--this.textContent<=0) alert('You\'ve won!');" value="10">10</button>
      <script>
        //Fundo no corpo da página
        let body = document.body;
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTNylMnVaVWb0dAzVvBOxf8BiyTGlS8WK_3UZ1l2G0Ut0WfFb_Y)';
      
        let btn = document.getElementById('bcen');
        btn.style.width = "300px"; //Size
        btn.style.height = "300px"; //Size
        btn.style.fontSize = "200px"; //size   
        btn.style.color = 'red'
        btn.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxcBMtRs4ePVWb1m3pTBeALxaO_jIDZMMeTccOW-F7rCN4krU)';
        btn.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        btn.style.borderRadius = "50%";
        btn.style.outline = "none";
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Opa obrigado! Tem como fazer o mesmo pra colocar uma imagem de fundo?

Comment: Isso já coloca a imagem de fundo (`background-image`)

Comment: Não então alem de eu colocar uma imagem para o botão,eu tambem consigo colocar uma no fundo branco?

Comment: @20Buscar é a mesma coisa, basta trocar o elemento que vai receber o fundo, editei a pergunta com isso

Answer (score 1):

Puro CSS inline - `style="background-image:url('endereçoImagem');`

```html
 <button style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8KVP.png'); width:250px; height:250px; font-size: 200px; color:red; background-color: transparent; border-radius: 50%; outline:none" id="bcen" onclick="if(--this.textContent<=0) alert('You\'ve won!');" value="10">10</button>
```

Comment: @sam yes, `w` Representação numérica do dia da semana - 0 (para domingo) .....

Comment: Leo posso fazer o mesmo pra colocar uma imagem de fundo?

Comment: @20Buscar, não entendi, colocar aonde?

Comment: Colocar uma imagem no fundo branco! Esse codigo que você me passou era pra colocar a imagem em um botão certo? Então eu queria tambem pra colocar no fundo ou background!?

Comment: @20Buscar, você se refere colocar uma imagem como plano de fundo de uma página? Isso também resolve `<body style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8KVP.png')";>` Não deixe de marcar uma resposta que melhor atendeu sua pergunta como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png